# express.js and soap calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, express

I am using express.js, node.js and node-soap.js and I am getting an error I can not fix.

I have the following code which fails with an exception and I can not see anything in the exception.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL';

var args = {
    symbol : 'AMZN'
};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.GetQuote(args, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

and in the console all I see is:

```
{ GetQuoteResult: [ 'exception' ] }
```

Thoughts?

Reza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code that finally got working...

```
var args1 = {"tns:symbol": "AMZN"};
var url1 = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL";
soap.createClient(url1, function(err, client) {
    console.log(client.describe().StockQuote.StockQuoteSoap.GetQuote);
    client.StockQuote.StockQuoteSoap.GetQuote(args1, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```